# Как получить все ассоциативные массивы по ключу?

Tags: php, массивы, база-данных

Есть массив, который я получаю из БД (через `mysqli_fetch_all`), в каждом из них есть ключ (который является id из другой таблицы). Мне нужно наименее трудозатратным способом достать эти массивы. Вот пример массива:

```
[
    0 => [
           'post_id' => '4'
           'thread_id' => '1'
           'username' => 'user'
           'message' => 'Сообщение'
         ]
    1 => [
           'post_id' => '7'
           'thread_id' => '2'
           'username' => 'user'
           'message' => 'Сообщение'
         ]
    2 => [
           'post_id' => '9'
           'thread_id' => '1'
           'username' => 'user'
           'message' => 'Сообщение'
         ]
]
```

Из этого него мне нужно получить все ассоциативные массивы, в которых `thread_id == '1'`, т.е. чтобы получился такой массив:

```
[
    0 => [
           'post_id' => '4'
           'thread_id' => '1'
           'username' => 'user'
           'message' => 'Сообщение'
         ]
    1 => [
           'post_id' => '9'
           'thread_id' => '1'
           'username' => 'user'
           'message' => 'Сообщение'
         ]
]
```

Знаю, что можно пройтись просто циклом и проверять какое значение `thread_id`, но я думаю что это будет работать не так быстро, т.к. каждый раз будет проходиться по всем элементам. Смотрел документацию php, но я там того что мне надо не нашел, возможно плохо искал.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE thread_id = 1`

Comment: Не совсем мой случай. Потому что я делаю такой запрос: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE message LIKE "%сообщение%"` и такой же запрос но для другой таблицы. Нужно это для того, чтобы сделать "поиск" и потом подсчитать количество совпадений, для поиска релевантных статей

Comment: напишите `where thread_id = 1 and message like '%message%'` в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уж не знаю как у Вас устроена БД. Но, я бы конечно тоже как и комментаторы использовал `sql`-запрос, чтобы `наименее затратным` способом получить нужные Вам данные. Но, как говорится, хозяин-барин. Раз у Вас возникло желание сделать это на `php`, то как говорится `получите и распишитесь`

```php
$data = [
    0 => [
           'post_id' => '4',
           'thread_id' => '1',
           'username' => 'user',
           'message' => 'Сообщение'
         ],
    1 => [
           'post_id' => '7',
           'thread_id' => '2',
           'username' => 'user',
           'message' => 'Сообщение'
         ],
    2 => [
           'post_id' => '9',
           'thread_id' => '1',
           'username' => 'user',
           'message' => 'Сообщение'
         ]
];

function arraySearchByKeyAndValue($keyValue = [], $searchArray = [] ) {
    $result = [];
    if ( is_array( $keyValue ) && count( $keyValue ) > 0 && is_array( $searchArray ) && count( $searchArray ) > 0) {
        foreach( $keyValue as $searchKey => $searchValue ) {
            foreach( $searchArray as $sArray ) {
                if ( is_array( $sArray ) && count( $sArray ) > 0 ) {
                    if ( in_array( $searchKey, array_keys( $sArray ) ) && $sArray[$searchKey] == $searchValue && !in_array( $sArray, $result ) ) {
                        $result[] = $sArray;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}


$result = arraySearchByKeyAndValue( [ 'thread_id' => '1' ], $data );
var_dump( $result )
```

Функция получилась довольно гибкой. Вы можете искать сразу по нескольким условиям (учтите, что условия не "суммируются" а-ля "AND" в `sql` )

```php
$result = arraySearchByKeyAndValue( [ 'thread_id' => '1', 'post_id' => '4' ], $data );
```